# How to select a self-closing bracket

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of self closing `<use />` tags that I want to replace with `<use></use>` to appease ie11.

E.g. `<use xlink:href="#fas-times-circle"/>` I want to become `<use xlink:href="#fas-times-circle"></use>`

I therefore just want to select the ending `/>` that matches a tag starting wiht `<use`.

I've got this far with my regex:

```
(?=><use)*(\/>)
```

However for some reason this is picking up the odd stray tag in my HTML, like `<path />`. I can only assume I am not being specific enough in my query.

Where am I going wrong? For reference I am using Pycharm so I guess the regex flavour is Python.

*** Edit ****

Example use case:

```
<use xlink:href="#fas-times-circle"/>
<path blah />
<br />
<use something xlink:href="#fas-times-square"/>
```

Becomes:

```
<use xlink:href="#fas-times-circle"></use>
<path blah />
<br />
<use something xlink:href="#fas-times-square"></use>
```

Comment: HTML is notoriously difficult to parse with regexes in the general case. This particular pattern should be doable, but the more specific you can make it, the less likely you are to have headaches. For instance, does it always have that one attribute, and does the attribute always have a similar value? Also, I'm not sure why you need lookaround here, isn't the "use" part of the match?

Comment: Thanks. I just want to select the ending `/>` so I guess the lookahead is required?

Comment: As an aside, note that HTML has never specified and does not use a closing slash on any HTML tag.

Comment: @Rob "never" is a bit strong - for a brief period some years ago, XHTML was considered to be "the future of HTML", so self-closing elements were The Thing To Do. Nowadays, "XHTML5" is considered to be "an alternative form of HTML5 that's well-formed XML". The picture is further muddied because this appears to be embedded SVG, which would normally be an XML format, but can be written using HTML syntax rules because ... well, I guess somebody thought that was a good idea.

Comment: @IMSoP "Never" is the correct word. You will NEVER find ANY HTML specification that mentions, specifies or requires--by word or example--using a closing slash. Also, XHTML is XML and XML is what requires the closing slash.

Comment: @IMSoP *sigh* Title: The XML Syntax

Comment: @Rob Yes, that is the heading of **a section in an HTML specification**. You could potentially read the [XHTML 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) as calling XHTML a separate language from HTML, but the WHATWG has no such separate standard, it [explicitly defines an abstract document model and two equally valid syntaxes for that model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml). One of those syntaxes, since it is built on top of XML, requires closing slashes; the other, based on a more pragmatic parsing model, does not.

Comment: @IMSoP You are grasping at straws for an invalid and inconsequential point. Quit wasting your time.

Comment: @Rob The links I gave are to the WHATWG HTML Standard, which is not by any definition "an XML specification". There is no longer a separate XHTML specification, and the term "XHTML" is no longer used in the combined standard, so the statement "self-closing tags are required in HTML if using the XML syntax" is completely valid and true. It is certainly not _common_ to use that syntax, but there is a current HTML specification which defines it as a correct variant of HTML, which is why I disagreed with the use of "never".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you need will depend on exactly how you try to replace it. Here is one way:

```
import re

re.sub(r"(<use .*?)/>", r"\1></use>", yourVariableHere)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aGGIuG/2)

Comment: Thanks; I just want to select the ending `/>` but I think your demo selects the whole tag. How would I amend this?

Comment: I think you need to share more code to explain what you're planning to do with the match.

Comment: Ok thank you, but the edit just confirms that the code I have already posted will do what you need. If you are doing search and replace in pyCharm, search for `(<use .*?)/>` and replace with `$1></use>`. The `$1` vs `\1` is the only difference between pyCharm and the Python code

Comment: If you really, really want to match only the `/>` for whatever reason (even though, as I said, my code above will get you your desired result), that is difficult because variable length look-behinds are not allowed. So I'm actually not sure how to do it without using the special character `\K`, which Python does not include in its `re` module. The module `regex` does include it, however. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hJP4M7/1/

Comment: Thanks, `(<use .*?)/>` selects the whole tag to replace (even with `$1></use>, not just the `/>`.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but when you use `$1></use>` in the *replace* field (not the search field), the tag will be replaced with the format you need.